# converting map coordinates to lat/long

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

Having received a very helpful and useful solution to my problem of contouring irregular data,[Contours with map overlay on irregular grid in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20892251/contours-with-map-overlay-on-irregular-grid-in-python), here  I still have the problem of combining the contours with the basemap. For this I know I have to do:
`x,y = m(lon,lat)`.
None of the SO posts I have seen corresponds to my needs. My problem is where do I get (from my various parameters available) the `x,y` that the `lon, lat` use in the above formula?
Here is my map object:

```
m = Basemap(projection = 'merc',llcrnrlon = 21, llcrnrlat = -18, urcrnrlon = 34, urcrnrlat = -8, resolution='h')
```

and here is the data for contours and the gridding:

```
data = pd.read_csv('meansr.txt', delim_whitespace=True)
numcols, numrows = 300, 300
xi = np.linspace(data.Lon.min(), data.Lon.max(), numcols)
yi = np.linspace(data.Lat.min(), data.Lat.max(), numrows)
xi, yi = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)

x, y, z = data.Lon.values, data.Lat.values, data.Z.values
zi = griddata(x, y, z, xi, yi)
```

Here are the plotting commands

```
plt.figure()
plt.contourf(xi, yi, zi)
plt.scatter(data.Lon, data.Lat, c=data.Z, s=100,
vmin=zi.min(), vmax=zi.max())
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

This gives me two plots, a basemap and contours side by side, which I think is due to the difference in the two coordinates. Pointing inside the contours indicates the correct latitudes and longitudes, while on the map the `x, y` displayed are very large, order of 2000 and above.
Any help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed my reply a bit, so that what i typed in reply to your changed version of your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20950887/2393569 works with the same names/... as in your code you gave here:

```
data = pd.read_csv('meansr.txt', delim_whitespace=True) 
numcols, numrows = 30, 30 
xi = np.linspace(data.Lon.min(), data.Lon.max(), numrows)
yi = np.linspace(data.Lat.min(), data.Lat.max(), numcols)
xi, yi = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)
x, y, z = data.Lon, data.Lat, data.Z

# NOTE: from here on it changes
points = np.vstack((x,y)).T 
values = z
wanted = (xi, yi)
zi = griddata(points, values, wanted) # for more info on griddata: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html

# from here its the same code again as you had
plt.figure()
plt.contourf(xi, yi, zi)
plt.scatter(data.Lon, data.Lat, c=data.Z, s=100, vmin=zi.min(), vmax=zi.max())
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

so the problem you actually had was not fully understanding `scipy.interpolate.griddata`, and not really a problem related to matplotlib.

So the correct use is

```
scipy.interpolate.griddata(points, values, xi, method='linear', fill_value=nan)
# 'points' has to contain what you named  x and y
# 'values' has to contain what you named z
# 'xi' has to contain what you named xi,yi
```

Does the plotting still give you trouble after you change this?

Note: i assume your imports are:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
import pylab as plt
# i guess the pd.read_csv is something pandas (heard of it, but never used it before, but since the only thing you do is read_csv i guess that wont cause problems)
```

It is best to give your imports too, if you ask a question here, since i just found out that `from matplotlib.mlab import griddata` exists too, and with a similar syntax to what you used, in [Contours with map overlay on irregular grid in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20892251/contours-with-map-overlay-on-irregular-grid-in-python) you use the griddata from scipy, but the answer, on which you seem to have based your follow-up question (this one) contains the matplotlib.mlab import of griddata (which works differently). Does this solve your confusion?

Comment: excuse my ommissin, the code above works as well as the code you provided here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20939838/use-of-matlab-meshgrid/20950887#20950887. I just did not notice it. But my problem remains combining the basemap with the contours which is why my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21061710/overlaying-a-basemap-on-contours.