# use of matlab meshgrid

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

Sorry i have to keep coming back to the problem gridding irregularly spaced data. I do not seem to see any clear responses to questions of how to grid data to a regular grid and the software documentation to me is good for those who already know.
I have x, y, z data on 29 points, with a header "Lon Lat Z". to plot contours with this data here is what I do:

1. After reading in the data, make a 300 by 300 point regular grid onto which to interpolate

   ```
   numcols, numrows = 300, 300
   xi = np.linspace(data.Lon.min(), data.Lon.max(), numcols)
   yi = np.linspace(data.Lat.min(), data.Lat.max(), numcols)
   xi, yi = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)
   ```

   Print xi and print yi at this point gives me x and y according to my data, interpolated over 300x300 points.
2. Interpolate the data over the grid created above

   ```
   x, y, z = data.Lon.values, data.Lat.values, data.Z.values
   zi = griddata(x, y, z, xi, yi)
   ```

   At this point if I do `print zi` I get

   > [[-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
   >   [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
   >   [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
   >   ...,
   >   [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
   >   [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
   >   [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]]

I was expecting to see values of interpolated z. I also have a map object defined to be overlaid by contours. The plotting function gives me separate figures, for the basemap and for the contours, with the correct contour values.
My question is why am I getting blank values for contours and how come they are plotted correctly?
For completeness here is my plotting function

```
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(8,4.5))
im = plt.contourf(xi, yi, zi)
plt.show()
```

Two plots come up (a base map and contours side by side)

Any help please.

Comment: obvious typo: in xi and yi, you use numcols, shouldnt that be numrows and numcols? Another thing: can you indent your post better? since at a certain moment you say "1." but there comes no "2." ?

Comment: Thanks @usethedeathstar for pointing out the typo error. 1. is reading in the data and creating the grid and 2. is there, which is interpolating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work:

```
numcols, numrows = 300, 300
xi = np.linspace(data.Lon.min(), data.Lon.max(), numrows)
yi = np.linspace(data.Lat.min(), data.Lat.max(), numcols)
xi, yi = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)

x, y, z = data.Lon.values, data.Lat.values, data.Z.values
points = np.vstack((x,y)).T
values = z
wanted = (xi, yi)
zi = griddata(points, values, wanted)
```

So that last line is how `griddata` works (assuming you use `scipy.interpolate.griddata`?)
The problem you have is that you seem to give `griddata` five arguments, while if i look at http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html#scipy.interpolate.griddata It says the following:

```
scipy.interpolate.griddata(points, values, xi, method='linear', fill_value=nan)
```

So in your case, giving five arguments is where it goes wrong I guess (confirm if it works if you do it like this, since I don't have your data so I can't test if it gives the correct result).

So in your case, your points where the values are known are the x, while the values which are known at that point are the y-values, and the points where you want to know them are at the z-values. No idea how the `method='linear'` copes with your argument, and the `fill_value` you give in is bad too, so you should just give the right inputs (which I think are correct the way I formulated them), and then it should work right.

edit: read in your data as a txt, and wrote the following code. Can you run it to see if that is the result you wanted?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
class d():
    def __init__(self):
        A0 = open("test.txt","rb") # i just copypasted your data into a txt (without first row), and reading it in in this class, so that the names are the same as yours
        A1 = A0.readlines()
        A = np.zeros((len(A1),3))
        for i, l in enumerate(A1):
            li = l.split()
            A[i,0] = float(li[0])
            A[i,1] = float(li[1])
            A[i,2] = float(li[2])
        self.Lon = A[:,0]
        self.Lat = A[:,1]
        self.Z = A[:,2]

data = d()
numcols, numrows = 30, 30
xi = np.linspace(data.Lon.min(), data.Lon.max(), numrows)
yi = np.linspace(data.Lat.min(), data.Lat.max(), numcols)
xi, yi = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)

x, y, z = data.Lon, data.Lat, data.Z
points = np.vstack((x,y)).T
values = z
wanted = (xi, yi)
zi = griddata(points, values, wanted)
import pylab as plt
fig = plt.figure(0, figsize=(8,4.5))
im = plt.contourf(xi, yi, zi)
plt.colorbar()
fig2 = plt.figure(1, figsize=(8,4.5))
im = plt.scatter(xi, yi, c= zi)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Comment: thanks you pointed me in the right direction. Now "print zi" gives me an array like before but with nan everywhere. I will keep working on this based on the scipy link you have indicated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @ZiloreMumba that is strange, can you print some of your data? so i can test where it is wrong? It is probably due to mixing up xi and yi somewhere, since it will give nan (due to the fill_value) if you are out of the convex area bounded by your points

Comment: you can see the data on my previous SO post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20892251/contours-with-map-overlay-on-irregular-grid-in-python, and here is of it: Lon   Lat     Z   Z2  pos
32.6  -13.6   41   9  CHIP
27.1  -16.9   43  12  CHOM
32.7  -10.2   46  14  ISOK
24.2  -13.6   33  13  KABO
28.5  -14.4   43  11  KABW
28.1  -12.6   33  16  KAFI
27.9  -15.8   46  13  KAFU
24.8  -14.8   44   9  KAOM
31.1  -10.2   35  14  KASA
25.9  -13.5   24   8  KASE
29.1   -9.8   10  13  KAWA
25.8  -17.8   39  11  LIVI
33.2  -12.3   44   8  LUND

Comment: @ZiloreMumba what values do you get if you use method='nearest' ? since i guess its somewhere xi,yi which are reversed or something in your code, causing it to give the fill_value nearly everywhere

Comment: Thanks for your effort @usethedeathstar. I will come back to you late, let me try to fiddle around. When I put method='nearest' I do get some values with print zi, though they appear to be wrong and the contours drawn are strange. When I use method='cubic' I get nan but the contours are correct. So let me go over the code again.

Comment: @ZiloreMumba I edited my code a bit, and it works fine for me now, can you try if it works for you now too?

Comment: thanks very much the code works very well. I actually added a comment just below the edited code you sent me.

Comment: @ZiloreMumba You should not ask a new question by trying to edit my answer, but ask a new question instead, and link to the previous questions and answers in your new question than, and post the code you have, and where it goes wrong, what the results are that you get, and what the results are that you expected to get, and what lines you think it goes wrong

Comment: @ZiloreMumba no problem, just ask another question and it will get answered ;-) just dont edit peoples answers to ask them another question