# pcolormesh () and contourf() do not work

Tags: python, matplotlib

Esteemed experts, am back with a problem I presented about two months ago, I have been working on it since with no success. This concerns superposition of contours on a basemap. I have looked at numerous examples on this, e.g. the example here: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/Unidata/tds-python-workshop/blob/master/matplotlib.ipynb
A sample of the data is on one of my previous posts, here: [Contours with map overlay on irregular grid in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20892251/contours-with-map-overlay-on-irregular-grid-in-python).
After preparing the data, here are plotting methods:

```
# Setting the plot size and text
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))

lev = [15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40,45]
norm1 = colors.BoundaryNorm(lev, 256)

# Draw filled contours

# 1. pcolor does not show the filled contours 
#cs = plt.pcolor(x,y,zi, cmap = cm.jet, norm = norm1)

# 2. pcolormesh does not show the filled contours
#cs = plt.pcolormesh(x,y,zi, shading = "flat", cmap=cmap)

# 3. contourf does not show the filled contours
#cs = plt.contourf(xi, yi, zi) #, levels=np.linspace(zi.min(),zi.max(),5))
cs = plt.contourf(xi, yi, zi, cmap = cm.jet, levels = lev, norm = norm1)

# 4. Draw line contours with contour()
#cs = m.contour(x,y,zi,linewidths=1.2)              # This works

plt.scatter(data.Lon, data.Lat, c=data.Z, s=100,
            vmin=zi.min(), vmax=zi.max())           # Does not work at all

# Color bar
#cbar = m.colorbar(fig,location='right',pad="10%")
fig.colorbar(cs)

# Plot a title
plt.figtext(.5,.05,'Figure 1. Mean Rainfall Onset Dates',fontsize=12,ha='center')

plt.show()
```

Sorry I am not able to post the plot examples, but:

- `pcolor`, `pcolormesh` and `contourf` above all give a map without any filled contours but with a colorbar
- the above plots without the map object give filled contours including scatter plot (without map background)
- contour gives the map with contour lines superposed:

I am baffled because this is an example copy-pasted from the example in the link quoted above.

Any hint as to a possible cause of the problem would be appreciated
Zilore Mumba

Comment: Could you post example values of `xi`, `yi`, `zi`?

Comment: This doesn't seem to 'copy-pasted' from the examples you provided.  The examples plot on an `Axes` object (i.e. `fig, ax = plt.subplots()` or `ax = fig.add_subplot(111)`).

Comment: @Bill the data is exactly as on the link iv) "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20892251/contours-with-map-overlay-on-irregular-grid-in-python". My code was copy-pasted from the unidata code and modified according to my data. I could not run their code exactly because I do not have their data. There may be differences in code, and this is because I tried several combinations. The basemap part (which I did not give) is also the similar to unidata.

Comment: I would appreciate if there are any climate/geo scientists who have code that works with filed contours and basemap, who can share it maybe I could learn something.

Comment: I uploaded a script + input-data to plot filled contours with basemap that which works for me

http://www.climate.unibe.ch/~roth/SO/

Comment: @Roth, excuse me I did not see your post until this late. I hope I can still reach you. I tried your example and it works very well. Thank you very much, it will provide a lot of learning for me.

Answer (score 3):

you need to use the basemap to plot the contours vs using matplotlib.pyplot. see my example for some of my code.

```
#Set basemap and grid
px,py=n.meshgrid(x,y)

m=Basemap(projection='merc',llcrnrlat=20,urcrnrlat=55,
   llcrnrlon=230,urcrnrlon=305,resolution='l')

X,Y=m(px,py)


#Draw Latitude Lines
#labels[left,right,top,bottom]  1=True 0=False
parallels = n.arange(0.,90,10.)
m.drawparallels(parallels,labels=[1,0,0,0],fontsize=10,linewidth=0.)

# Draw Longitude Lines
#labels[left,right,top,bottom]  1=True 0=False
meridians = n.arange(180.,360.,10.)
m.drawmeridians(meridians,labels=[0,0,0,1],fontsize=10,linewidth=0)

#Draw Map
m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawcountries()
m.drawstates()
m.fillcontinents(color='grey',alpha=0.1,lake_color='aqua')

#Plot Contour lines and fill
levels=[5.0,5.1,5.2,5.3,5.4,5.6,5.7,5.8,5.9,6.0]
cs=m.contourf(px,py,thickness,levels,cmap=p.cm.RdBu,latlon=True,extend='both')
cs2=m.contour(px,py,thickness,levels,latlon=True,colors='k')

#Plot Streamlines
m.streamplot(px,py,U,V,latlon=True,color='k')

#Add Colorbar
cbar = p.colorbar(cs)
cbar.add_lines(cs2)
cbar.ax.set_ylabel('1000 hPa - 500 hPa Thickness (km)')

#Title
p.title('Geostrophic Winds with Geopotential Thickness')


p.show()
```

[image: my figure]

Comment: Thanks @Cwilliams for the code. It will be very useful for me. Could you send me the line which reads the data. It looks to me your data is model output, or at least it looks to be on a regular grid. Would you have an example which plots data from stations which are only over the continental US?

Comment: This is ncep reanalysis data which is gridded already for the globe. The x,y in my code are variables I names with my Lon,lat arrays respectively. I used Scientific python to read in the .nc file

Comment: I don't think you need the line `X,Y=m(px,py)` since you never use `X` or `Y`.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing how your data look like it's a bit difficult to answer your question, but I'll try anyway. You might want to grid your data, for example, with an histogram, then contour the results.

For example, if you're interested in plotting 2D contours of points that have coordinates (`x`,`y`) and a third property (`z`) you want to use for the colors, you might give this a try

```
from numpy import *

H=histogram2d(x,y,weights=z)

contourf(H[0].T,origin='lower')
```

But, like I said, it's hard to understand what you're looking for if you're not giving details about your data. Have a look at the matplotlib guide for more examples http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/contourf_demo.html

Comment: thank you very much for your effort.Just a bit more clarification, I am doing a 2-D contour plot with a basemap overlay. With the code you provided, on the line "H=histogram2d(x,y,weights=z)" I get "ValueError: too many values to unpack". My domain is in the interior of Africa with no coastline. I have noted that when I extend the domain to the whole of Africa and surrounding oceans, I actually do get filled contours over the ocean and nothing over land. contour() puts contours both over land and over the continent. So my problem narrows down to "why filled contours over ocean only?".

Comment: I can almost certainly confirm that this seems to be software is, perhaps a limitation of the software. Examples, e.g. here "http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/examples.html (contour lines over filled continent background" behave the same.

Comment: Eventually, thanks to @Roth (private communication) my problem is resolved. In case it may be of use to others, Dr. Roth pointed out to me that "SciPy's griddata returns nan's for the range outside of the valid points--> contourf cannot handle this, we need to use numpy's masked arrays" and he gave the following line which resolves the problem "zi=np.ma.masked_invalid(zi)". Thanks Dr. Roth and thanks all.